# Is there any reason that two Advanced PDF forms for the same transaction would draw data differently?

Tags: image, netsuite, freemarker

I have an Advanced PDF Form in Netsuite that prints Sales Proposals with pictures, and also an Order Acknowledgement. The code is very similar. Recently we decided to add them to the Picking Ticket, and I basically copied and pasted what I had on the Order Ack - because the data for both comes from the Sales Order in Netsuite.

For some reason the images just won't show on the picking ticket. I have tried changing the source code slightly, like using `record.item` etc., but the table starts with `<#list record.item as item>` so I shouldn't need that.

```
<td colspan="7" line-height="150%" style="vertical-align:top;">
<#if item.custcol_item_image_url?starts_with("http")>
<img src="${item.custcol_item_image_url}" style="height:40px;width:40px;margin:1px" />
</#if></td>
```

Basically I'm just getting a blank. FYI I also have another field that references from the Sales Order in the same way, ie. `${item.custcol_xyz}` and that one works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom field needs to be set to "show" on the Sales Order form in order for it to be available in your template. Customize your form, and under the Sublist Fields subtab, ensure that the field is question is checked to display on the form.

If you want to hide it in the UI, there is a workaround that you can try, which is to clear the label for the field. This works most of the time, but not always.

Comment: Perfecy, thanks michoel! Man that had me boxed, but both your suggestions work perfectly.